# C# - Order by multiple properties of an object

Tags: c#

If I want to order a list based on more than one property, I can't see a good way of doing that other than forming those properties to numbers and then using `OrderBy`, for instance:

```
int someArbitraryNumber = 1000;

List<Tuple<int, int>> test = new List<Tuple<int, int>>() {
  new Tuple<int, int>(1, 3),
  new Tuple<int, int>(1, 4),
  new Tuple<int, int>(1, 5),
  new Tuple<int, int>(2, 3),
  new Tuple<int, int>(9, 15)
};

var orderedTest = test
  .OrderBy(x => x.Item1 + x.Item2 * someArbitraryNumber);
```

Here I'd be looking to for the resulting list to be:

```
    (1, 3),
    (2, 3),
    (1, 4),
    (1, 5),
    (9, 15)
```

That is to say, first ordered by the second item, then by the first.

Comment: maybe a sample list of input and required output would help,  `ThenBy` and `ThenByDescending` may do the trick - 
`var orderedTest = test.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenBy(x => x.Item2);` or 
`var orderedTest1 = test.OrderBy(x => x.Item1).ThenByDescending(x => x.Item2);`

Comment: @DawoodAwan Thanks, `ThenBy` is exactly what I needed, and I've now added some example output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ThenBy()`:

```
int someArbitraryNumber = 10000; // Not used anymore

List<Tuple<int, int>> test = new List<Tuple<int, int>>() {
  new Tuple<int, int>(1, 3),
  new Tuple<int, int>(1, 4),
  new Tuple<int, int>(1, 5),
  new Tuple<int, int>(2, 3),
  new Tuple<int, int>(9, 15)
};

var orderedTest = test.OrderBy(x => x.Item2).ThenBy(x => x.Item1);
```

---

#### Other improvments

- Use `var` if the type of a variable can be figured out by the compiler
- Use ValueTuples, it's less verbose (`(int, int)` instead of `Tuple<int, int>`) and you can use names for the items

```
var test = new List<(int first, int second)>()
{
    (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (9, 15)
};

var orderedTest = test.OrderBy(x => x.second).ThenBy(x => x.first);
```

Comment: Many thanks, this is exactly what I needed; thanks for the tips, though in this case was just thrown together for an example

Comment: You're welcome. :)